# jQuery setTimeout() callback not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble figuring out how the `$("identifier").remove` works with `setTimeout()`. The code below tries to animate a snowflake dropping down

```
    //construct a html string
    var html_str = "<img class='snowflakes' src = 'snowflake1.png' style='position: absolute; left: " + String(pos_x) + "px'> "

    //Append the element to field
    var flake = $(html_str).appendTo('#field');

    flake.animate({top: String(FIELD_SIZE-FLAKE_SIZE)+'px'}, 
                    drop_speed,

                    //callback function when finished animating
                    function(){
                        setTimeout(function(){flake.remove();},1000);
                    }
    );
```

I don't get how

```
    setTimeout(function(){flake.remove();},1000); //this works
    setTimeout(flake.remove,1000); //but this doesn't remove the element
```

It seemed to me both should perform the same function. What is going on here?

Comment: Both call the same `.remove()` function, but with different values for `this` within the function.

Answer (score 3):

The second one didn't work because it was executed in the global context. Here is an article regarding the `this` context in the function passed to setTimeout, as per [MDN (Check 'The "this" problem)'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_.22this.22_problem)

Your code, if written this way, would work:

```
setTimeout(flake.remove.bind(flake),1000);
```